# ng-model not updating in directive

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

There seems to be an issue with my ng-model binding to filterDetails.value.  It will display the value "Test", but when I update the value to "Test1234" and click the button to execute filterColumn(), the alert displays "Test" instead of the updated value. If I then update the value again to "Test12345" and click the filter button it displays "Test1234".  It is always one update behind. I am using angular version 1.2.24.  This particular pop over is being used inside a header cell template in a ng-grid.  I added a popover to something else on the page and it works fine so it does appear to be related to using it in the ng-grid.

```
 app.directive('popOver', function ($compile) {
        var filterTemplate = "<div><input type=\"text\" ng-model=\"filterDetails.value\"></input><button style=\"margin-left:5px;\" ng-click=\"filterColumn()\">Filter</button></div>";
        var getTemplate = function () {
            var template = filterTemplate;
            return template;
        }
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {


                scope.filterDetails =
                        {
                            value: "Test"

                        };
                scope.filterColumn = function () {
                    alert(scope.filterDetails.value);
                };


                var popOverContent;
                var html = getTemplate();
                popOverContent = $compile(html)(scope);
                var options = {
                    content: popOverContent,
                    placement: "bottom",
                    html: true,
                    title: scope.title,
                    container: "body"
                };
                $(element).popover(options);


            },
            scope: false
    };
    });
```

Comment: your code seems fine.. can your create a fiddle/plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of angular are you using? You may need to upgrade your version of angular. I put together a quick jsfiddle with your directive in it, and it seems to be working ok for me using angular 1.3.15 AND 1.2.28

```
//angular 1.3.15
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x5o9s27a/

```
//angular 1.2.28
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ge7bqh4n/

Comment: I created another jsfiddle with the ng-grid headerCellTemplate and your specific version of angular, and I am still not seeing the issue you explained. Can you take a look at the jsfiddle and see how it differs from your problem, or create a new fiddle that does reproduce the problem?
http://jsfiddle.net/TwitchBronBron/96ahLpcr/

Comment: Thanks.  It appears the issue is related to the bootstrap modal that I am displaying everything in.  Though I am not sure why there is an issue yet.

Comment: This jsfiddler is closer to what I have, though the popover is completely broken in it.  http://jsfiddle.net/bkoma0xa/1/

Comment: Switching to the modal in ui.bootstrap resolved the issue.  I should have been using it in the first place. Thanks for the help